# what would be ses5001 alternative?

Tags: dc-motor

I'm considering using l293B motor driver ic. But it seems i won't be able to get the ses5001 diode which they refer in the data sheet. What would be the best ses5001 alternative?

Comment: bit of browsing on the OnSemi site yields MUR220 200V 2A

Answer (score 1):

For substituting any semiconductor part, a search for the part number and "cross reference" yields functional or second-source equivalent part numbers.

For the SES5001 in the question, one such equivalent is the [OnSemi MUR120](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MUR120-D.PDF) switchmode power rectifier.

Comment: thanks for your answer. 1 more question - ses5001 says forward/output current of 2A, and MUR120 says 1A. is this worth considering or i'm fine with a 1A?

Comment: That would depend entirely on how much current you intend to draw for your specific circuit - Depends on the motors, the power supply, and so on.

Comment: lets say i'll be driving 2 motors (back and forth) and each with these features - 6VDC, draws 250mA(max. at free run), and stalls around 1 Amp.

Comment: Please post a separate question with a schematic. Word pictures don't help as much as schematic pictures.